# Determine the number which is crossed out twice in a polygon of 2000 vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose we have a regular polygon with 2000 vertices which are labeled as the natural numbers 1, 2, 3, ... etc. First, we cross out 1. Followed by, the next numbers which are crossed out are $16, 31, 46, \cdots$ in increasing order until one number is crossed twice. The question is: which number will it be and how many numbers are left out?

I understood there is some connection with congruence theory but I am in the darkroom and have no idea how to come up with a solution. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

the first number crossed out twice is 1

---

**Q)** which number is crossed out twice?

After one round, one gets back to $2011 (\mod 2000)\sim 11$. Therefore on one round, our cycle $\text{shift} = 10$ vertices. Now after two cycles, we get to $11+\text{shift}= 11+10(\mod 15)=21 (\mod 15) \sim 6$. After three cylces, we get to $6+\text{shift}=6+10 = 16(\mod 15) = 1$.

**Q)** How many numbers are left out?

In each cycle, we cover $\lfloor \frac{2000}{15} \rfloor = 133$ vertices, then on 3 cycles we cover 399. The rest are left out.